# How to fix 'tableview cellforrowat not called?'

Tags: swift, tableview

I'm setting up a tableview with customtableview cell, but when i run the app, the data is not shown.

I already check all the connection, identifier, class name, etc

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet var testingTableView: UITableView!
    var data = ["Indomie","Kacang Tanah","Soya"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        testingTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = testingTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! customTableViewCell
        cell.customLabel.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
}
```

This is my code for the table view, it's should call the cellforrowat but it's not

Comment: Set `testingTableView.dataSource = self` in `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: i'm using class UITableViewController

Comment: Why do you use an extra nib? You can design custom cells directly in the table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` implementation.

You have number of `data.count` section, but each section has 0 row.

Try replacing `numberOfSections(in:)` to `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need additional code as below-

```
testingTableView.delegate = self
testingTableView.datasource = self

testingTableView.reloadData() // I think you missed it!
```

Comment: The OP uses `UITableViewController` which has implicitly connected `delegate` and `datasource`.

Comment: the delegate and data source, should be automatically because, i use uitableviewcontroller right?

Comment: then just put testingTableView.reloadData() in viewdidload

Comment: thankyou for the answer, I already test that also, it's not working.

Comment: @Hanryang The framework calls `reloadData()` once after the view has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

1). Add this line

```
 @IBOutlet var testingTableView: UITableView! {
        didSet {
                  testingTableView.delegate = self
                  testingTableView.dataSource = self
              }
  }
```

2). You also can add this feature via Stroyboard. Click on your table and using right click drag the pointer on ViewController and add delegate and dataSource.

And i think you missed

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0 //As per your need.
}
```

Comment: The OP uses UITableViewController which provides a `tableView` property and connected `datasource` and `delegate` by default.

Comment: Add numberOfRowsInSection and return data.Count. In numberOfSections add return 1 or remove, numberOfSections by default return 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong API, `numberOfSections` returns the number of **sections** but you have to return the number of **rows**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { {
    return data.count
}
```

There is no need to override `numberOfRowsInSection`, the default value is `1`.

And delete

```
@IBOutlet var testingTableView: UITableView!
```

There is an implicit `tableView` property of `UITableViewController`